# Java Change tray icon

Tags: java, dynamic, replace, icons, tray

Hi i am trying to change a tray icon i have in java dynamically. E.g They icon is grey square. When a user clicks an item in my tray menu, i would like the grey square to switch images to a red square.

Here is my current code for the tray icon.

```
public class Utils {

    private static Image iconImage;
    private static Image iconImage2;
    private static SystemTray sysTray;
    private static PopupMenu menu;
    private static MenuItem item1;
    private static MenuItem item2;
    private static MenuItem item0;
    private static TrayIcon trayIcon;
    private static TrayIcon trayIcon2;

    public static void loadTrayIcon() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AC Tray Frame");

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3)); 

        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            sysTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            iconImage  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("osx_tray_icon.png");
            iconImage2  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("loading.gif");

            menu = new PopupMenu();

            item0 = new MenuItem("This is a test");
            item0.setEnabled(false);
            item1 = new MenuItem("Test");
            item2 = new MenuItem("Exit");

            menu.add(item0);
            menu.addSeparator();
            menu.add(item1);
            menu.addSeparator();
            menu.add(item2);

            item1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        system.out.println("hi");
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            item2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(iconImage, "Test Title", menu);

            try {
                sysTray.add(trayIcon);
            }
            catch(AWTException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want to use [`TrayIcon#setImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#setImage%28java.awt.Image%29) which will change the icon displayed by the `TrayIcon`